# mod rewrite issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How come this one works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/book/blabla$
RewriteRule ^.+$ /book/?name=blabla [NC,L]
```

But this one doesn't?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/book/blabla$ /book/?name=blabla [NC,L]
```

I've tried many things but it's confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file, the [contextual per-directory prefix of the URL path is removed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) before testing the rules:

> As you will see below, `RewriteRule` can be used in per-directory config files (*.htaccess*). In such a case, it will act locally, stripping the local directory prefix before processing, and applying rewrite rules only to the remainder.

That means if you use mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file in the root directory (`/`), that path prefix is removed from the URL path. So `/book/blabla` is reduced to `book/blabla`. Your rule pattern must reflect that behavior:

```
RewriteRule ^book/blabla$ /book/?name=blabla [NC,L]
```